# Pyspark Reduceby key with lambda function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, lambda

I have a RDD as

```
[(242, 3.0, 1.0), (302, 3.0, 1.0), (377, 1.0, 1.0)]
```

The first value is the key and the next 2 values need to be added according to their respective key. For example: if i have 2 entries for key 242 with values (3,1) and (4,1)
i need to get the final result as (7,2).
I am using the following code of spark reduceByKey() with lambda function as

```
averageRating = movieRatings.reduceByKey(lambda movie1, movie2: (movie1[0]+movie2[0], (movie1[1]+movie2[1])))
```

But the problem is when i do

```
averageRating.take(2)
```

it throws a huge compiler error.

Can someone evaluate the reduceByKey function that i have used? I think that is how it should be and can't seem to figure out the correct way to use the lambda function.

Comment: You can map your RDD's elements to pairs before performing your reduction: `movieRatings.map(lambda l: (l[0], (l[1], l[2]))).reduceByKey...`

Comment: it worked. what do you think was the problem? Does reduceByKey() requires mapping to be done before it can be applied?

Comment: The fact is that reduceByKey expects a pair of values per element, but I haven't looked at the doc/code for it.